# Show callout when my position is clicked

Tags: android, arcgis-android

I am using the Esri ArcGIS sdk on android, and I am trying to do the following:

- Get my position
- When my position is clicked, show a callout

So far i've been lucky in finishing the first one, by using a `locationServ` class

I've also created the callout and tested it, it's fine but my question here is how to make the map only show the callout when I click my position and not anywhere else on the map ?

Here's my code:

```
package com.appzgate.locator;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.esri.android.map.Callout;
import com.esri.android.map.GraphicsLayer;
import com.esri.android.map.LocationService;
import com.esri.android.map.MapView;
import com.esri.android.map.bing.BingMapsLayer;
import com.esri.android.map.bing.BingMapsLayer.MapStyle;
import com.esri.android.map.event.OnSingleTapListener;
import com.esri.android.toolkit.map.MapViewHelper;
import com.esri.core.geometry.GeometryEngine;
import com.esri.core.geometry.Point;
import com.esri.core.geometry.SpatialReference;
import com.esri.core.map.Graphic;
import com.esri.core.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol;

public class PlacelocatorActivity extends Activity {

MapView mMapView;
BingMapsLayer bing;
GraphicsLayer locationLayer;
LocationService loc;
private Callout m_callout;
private int m_calloutStyle;
private ViewGroup calloutContent;
Graphic graphic;
Point mLocation = null, p, mapPoint;
final SpatialReference wm = SpatialReference.create(102100);
final SpatialReference egs = SpatialReference.create(4326);
MapViewHelper mvHelper;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    mLocation = new Point();
    mMapView.enableWrapAround(true);
     mvHelper = new MapViewHelper(mMapView);

    m_calloutStyle = R.xml.identify_calloutstyle;
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    m_callout = mMapView.getCallout();
    // Get the layout for the Callout from
    // layout->identify_callout_content.xml
    calloutContent = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.identify_callout_content, null);
    m_callout.setContent(calloutContent);

    bing = new BingMapsLayer(
            "ArUDBy4hjDCywOK-GVofer_1U6GG3GPWxaZ8zp68o01W-nQdiLgcV9MtvGEehxn5",
            MapStyle.AERIAL);
    mMapView.addLayer(bing);

    loc = mMapView.getLocationService();
    loc.setLocationListener(new MyLocationListener());
    loc.start();
    loc.setAutoPan(false);
    mLocation = loc.getPoint();

    locationLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

    mMapView.addLayer(locationLayer);
    mMapView.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSingleTap(float x, float y) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // mapPoint = mMapView.toMapPoint(x, y);
            identifyLocation(x, y);
        }
    });
}

void identifyLocation(float x, float y) {

    // Hide the callout, if the callout from previous tap is still showing
    if (m_callout.isShowing()) {
        m_callout.hide();
    }

    Point mapPoint = mMapView.toMapPoint(x, y);

    checkGraphic();

    if (graphic != null) {
        ShowCallout(m_callout, graphic, mLocation);
    }
}

private void checkGraphic() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SimpleMarkerSymbol sms = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(Color.GREEN, 25,
            SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE.CROSS);

    Map<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hm.put("NAME", "Amman");
    hm.put("COUNTRY", "Jordan");
    graphic = new Graphic(mLocation, sms, hm);
    locationLayer.addGraphic(graphic);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.unpause();
}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public MyLocationListener() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * If location changes, update our current location. If being found for
     * the first time, zoom to our current position with a resolution of 20
     */
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        if (loc == null)
            return;
        boolean zoomToMe = (mLocation == null) ? true : false;
        mLocation = new Point(loc.getLongitude(), loc.getLatitude());
        if (zoomToMe) {

            p = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(mLocation, egs, wm);
            // graphic = new Graphic((Geometry) p, (Symbol) sms, hm);
            // locationLayer.addGraphic(graphic);
            mMapView.zoomToResolution(p, 20.0);
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Disabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS Enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

}

private void ShowCallout(Callout calloutView, Graphic graphic,
        Point mapPoint) {
    Log.v("call", "in the callout");
    // Get the values of attributes for the Graphic
    String cityName = (String) graphic.getAttributeValue("NAME");
    String countryName = (String) graphic.getAttributeValue("COUNTRY");
    // String cityPopulationValue = ((Double) graphic
    // .getAttributeValue("POPULATION")).toString();
    Log.v("call", "so far so good");
    // Set callout properties
    calloutView.setCoordinates(mapPoint);
    calloutView.setStyle(m_calloutStyle);
    calloutView.setMaxWidth(325);

    // Compose the string to display the results
    StringBuilder cityCountryName = new StringBuilder();
    cityCountryName.append(cityName);
    cityCountryName.append(", ");
    cityCountryName.append(countryName);

    TextView calloutTextLine1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.citycountry);
    calloutTextLine1.setText(cityCountryName);

    // Compose the string to display the results
    StringBuilder cityPopulation = new StringBuilder();
    cityPopulation.append("Population: ");
    // cityPopulation.append(cityPopulationValue);

    // TextView calloutTextLine2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.population);
    // calloutTextLine2.setText(cityPopulation);
    calloutView.setContent(calloutContent);
    calloutView.show();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've figured this on my own by adding the following code:

```
int loaded = mvHelper.addMarkerGraphic(loc.getLatitude(),
                    loc.getLongitude(), "Jordan", "Amman", null, icon,
                    false, 0);
```